# Does replaying an assassination still affect stocks?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I missed a few investment opportunities, and also did those missions way earlier in the game than I should have. If I replay those missions, will the stock market be re-affected?

(Attempting a replay pops a statement indicating that afterward, you will be restored to the point just *before* the replay, so my hunch is no. But I'm wondering if anyone's tried it yet, or if I need to restart to get my guys up to their nine-figure potential.)

Comment: 3,000 views in three days. Apparently I wasn't the only one wondering!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Currently, **replaying these missions will not have any effect on the stock prices.** Replaying missions is only to get a better rating.

The capacity to retroactively impact the stock market *may* be implemented in a future patch but this kind of change is fairly unlikely.

If you are looking for other stock market tips, here's a [fairly useful guide](http://geekfed.com/grand-theft-auto-5-stock-market-tips/323).

Comment: +1 This is correct. Replays are completely separate from the rest of the game. Their only use is to get more gold medals (aside from the nostalgia of replaying your favourite mission, of course). It's unlikely Rockstar will ever change that.

Comment: That's what I'd figured, and I did actually restart. If nothing else, now that I know the game I can optimize money, weapons and cars by going in a better order.

Comment: Jut so you know, your link is dead