# Does Grand Theft Auto 5 Hitch Lift 1 (Tinkle) random event repeat?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Has anyone seen this random event repeat? I've already played it once, and only realized after the amount of money I could have made off of it if it had happened to me later in the game. Some random events do repeat obviously like bike thefts and armored truck robberies, but I'm curious if anyone has seen or read this specific random event repeating? I want this to be available for later in the game too!

Comment: The only random events I've ever seen repeating are armored trucks and ATM robberies ($500 amounts).

Comment: i wish the strangers re-appear, as I want to bring them to the Cult.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Supposedly you can bring passengers picked up when in taxi to the cult too.

Comment: Yes, the criteria to trigger Taxi ride to Cult camp is to carry one of the guys in Hitch Lift 2 to 4  to the camp, and wait for **24 hours** .

Comment: I cannot confirm, but my guess would be that it doesn't repeat, as that could destroy the in-game economy with the stock repercussions.  I'm drawing on the fact that [Lester's assassination missions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132169/does-replaying-an-assassination-still-affect-stocks) do not affect the stock markets when replayed.

Comment: @Nolonar I saw also a woman asking for help. You follow her and a man is waiting for you and they steal your cash.

Answer (score 1):

some times the game dont register them and you can repeat it. I did the tinkle one twice, the second time with over $3.5b invested with each character ;)
 You can verify on Social club if it is registered